# Prove that $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1$ is not in the ideal $(5,\alpha+2)$ in $\mathbb{Z[\alpha]}$ where $\alpha=2^{1/3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm thinking about the theorem 3.24 in Marcus 'Number Fields', that is,

Let $p$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, and suppose $p$ is ramified in a number ring $R$. Then $p|disc(R)$.

I am considering $\mathbb{Z[\alpha]}$ where $\alpha=2^{1/3}$ and $p=5$ as an example, and I know that $5\mathbb{Z[\alpha]}=(5,\alpha+2)(5,\alpha^2-3\alpha+1)$. Also I proved that $||(5,\alpha^2-3\alpha+1)||=25$, so $(5,\alpha+2)$ is prime.

To verify that $5\mathbb{Z[\alpha]}$ is not prime, I should prove that $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1$ is not in the ideal $(5,\alpha+2)$ and $(5,\alpha^2-3\alpha+1)=Q^2$ where Q is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ but I can't do this.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1$ is in that ideat that I call $I$,

$\alpha(\alpha+2)$ is in $I$ implies that $\alpha^2-3\alpha+1-\alpha(\alpha+2)=-5\alpha+1\in I$, this implies that $5(\alpha+2)-5\alpha+1=9\in I$, this implies that $2(5)-9=1$ in $I$, can you show that $I$ is not $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

Comment: Really cool. Thank you very much. Then how I show that I is not a square of prime ideal?

Comment: @DDYBM You have shown that norm $N(5,\alpha^2-3\alpha+1)=25$ and we know $N(5)=5^3$, so $N(5,\alpha+2)=5$. Norm of square ideals must be a square: $N(I^2)=N(I)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=2^{\frac{1}{3}}$, and let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

In the ring $R$, let $I=(5,\alpha+2)$, and let $J=(I,\alpha^2+3a+1)$.

We want to show that $\alpha^2+3\alpha+1 \notin I$.

Equivalently, we want to show $I\ne J$.

Analyzing the ideal $J$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\alpha^2+3\alpha+1 \in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)-1\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-1\in J\qquad\text{[since $\alpha+2\in J$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&J=(1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, we want to show $I \ne (1)$.

Suppose instead that in the ring $R$, we have $I = (1)$.

Our goal is to derive a contradiction.

Note that $R$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-2)$.

By the correspondence theorem, $I=(1)$ in the ring $R$ if and only if $I'=(1)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, where $I'=(5,x+2,x^3-2)$.

Working in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we have
$$I'=(5,x+2,x^3-2)=(5,x+2)$$
since $x^3-2 = (x^2-2x+4)(x+2)-(2)(5)$.

By assumption, we have $1\in I'$, hence we can write 
$$f(x)(5) + g(x)(x+2)=1$$
for some $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

But then, substituting $x=-2$ into the above equation, we get
$$f(-2)(5) = 1$$
contradiction.

This completes the proof.